# How to group observations in column range?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column named `Age`.
How can I print out the number of observations in each age group?

```
Example age groups:   

20 - 25
25 - 30
30 - 35
35 - 40
40 - 45
50 - 50 

Age Column

11
7
49
31
16
33
55
47
```

Of course  I could use print with conditional in a loc statement, but that is really verbose.
Is there any better  way?

```
print(myDataFrame.loc[(myDataFrame.Age >= 20) & (myDataFrame.Age < 30)].count)

print(myDataFrame.loc[(myDataFrame.Age >= 30) & (myDataFrame.Age < 40)].count)

print(myDataFrame.loc[(myDataFrame.Age >= 40) & (myDataFrame.Age < 50)].count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One ways you can use `pd.Series.value_counts` with `bins` parameter:

```
df['Age Column'].value_counts(bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60], sort=False)
```

Output:

```
(-0.001, 10.0]    1
(10.0, 20.0]      2
(20.0, 30.0]      0
(30.0, 40.0]      2
(40.0, 50.0]      2
(50.0, 60.0]      1
Name: Age Column, dtype: int64
```

If you want to control you labelling more, you can use pd.cut and value_counts:

```
s = pd.cut(df['Age Column'], bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60], labels=['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60'])
s.value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
0-10     1
11-20    2
21-30    0
31-40    2
41-50    2
51-60    1
Name: Age Column, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The  problem is that ```value_counts``` returns only unique values. What happens if I have 33,15,33 ? it will count 33 only once?

Comment: Nope.... it counts the number of that value.   Try it. `pd.Series([33,12,33]).value_counts()`

Comment: That's beautiful :)

Comment: How can I add a condition to your solution on the same line to say that Gender == Male from myDataFrame? 
The way I usually do it, is to create new variable ```malesDF = myDataFrame.loc[(myDataFrame.Gender=='Male')]```

Comment: @bibscy... Yes, this is correct.  Filter your column first to on those values you want, then use value_counts and rename the results to match what you filtered on.

Comment: I had thought that I could do it all in fewer lines of code. Thanks again.

Comment: @bibscy You could do it using `groupby`. If you create some dummy data and add a new question, someone in the SO community will show you.